# Elevation of prayer of individual to congregation

Tags: salat, jinn, malaikah, adhan, jamaat

In hanabali fiqh, its a famous opinion that when an individual is praying alone and people join him, his prayer is elevated to status of congregation.

My question, Is the prayer of an individual elevated to status of congregation by angels or muslim jinns praying behind an individual, while praying alone, who gives call to prayer.

Report 1: the deeds are upon their intentions.

Report 2: if an individual intends martyrdom, Allah will give him the status if he dies in bed.

Report 3: Angels pray behind an individual when he prays in deserted land.

Report 4: the Muslim jinns are your brothers in Islam.

Report 5 : obligation on muslim jinns to respond to call of prayer.

Report 6 : an action has 10-700 times the reward.

If we combine all above reports it seems, angels or muslim jinn elevate the prayer of individual to status of congregational prayer, provided he has the intention and gives the call to prayer.